# How to group objects while exporting to CSV in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, business-intelligence

I am trying to export my report to a CSV file. But, upon exporting the file the values are appearing in the reverse order. Here is an example of my report layout with few columns for your reference.

[image: My Report layout]

The first one is a Tablix and the second one is a Textbox. When the user selects a date and if there are any records, the records as well as their count should be displayed. If there are no records, an informational message will be displayed. Let's assume I have some 10 records returned. Then, I would like to export that report to a CSV file. When exporting to CSV, the 'Total Employees' count is appearing on the top of the file and the records are appearing on the bottom of the report. However, I would like to have the records displayed first and the count at the bottom in the CSV file just like the report.

Also, I would like to know if the title "Total Employees" can be hidden displaying only the count when exported to CSV.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did a trick so that the SSRS Report displays in a neat way and the CSV file can be generated as expected.

I created a Matrix below the Tablix with only column that shows the count of the employees and has hidden the other rows when showing the report on web. This way it will only display the count on the web and when exported to CSV will show the Total count on the bottom of the records.